# SSLRequireCipher equivalent on Apache 2

Tags: ssl, https, apache2

In a recent security scan we did on our servers we got the following comment:

> Typically, for Apache/mod_ssl, httpd.conf or ssl.conf should have the following lines:
>      SSLProtocol -ALL +SSLv3 +TLSv1
>      SSLCipherSuite ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
>
> For Apache/apache_ssl include the following line in the configuration file (httpsd.conf):
>      SSLRequireCipher ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

the mod_ssl.conf file was updated as instructed
updating the apache2.con with this line:

> ```
> SSLRequireCipher ALL:!aNULL:!ADH:!eNULL:!LOW:!EXP:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM
> ```

And restarting Apache2 , I get:

> Invalid command 'SSLRequireCipher', perhaps misspelled or defined by a
>      module not included in the server configuration

I tried this line in the apache2.conf:

> SSLRequire %{SSL_CIPHER_USEKEYSIZE} >= 128

and Apache2 restarted successfully , but the on rerunning the scan I got the same:
*SSL Server Allows Anonymous Authentication Vulnerability*

Comment: Actually, "as instructed" should be the first options (SSLProtocol and SSLCipherSuite), not SSHRequireCipher. You're using Apache2 with its (integrated) mod_ssl (not Apache+SSL or the mod_ssl separate module, which was for Apache Httpd 1).

Answer (score 0):

Try [`SSLCipherSuite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslciphersuite) for the general configuration and [`SSLRequire`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslrequire) with a regexp on `%{SSL_CIPHER}` if you need a require for a specific part of your server.

**EDIT:**
If you're running on Ubuntu, the default configuration in `/etc/apache2/mods-enabled/ssl.conf` should solve your problems:

```
SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!ADH
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
```

Comment: (You generally won't need `SSLRequire` if you've configured `SSLCipherSuite` to a high-enough level.)